# Can we customize/branding salesforce1 App

Tags: salesforce1-app

[image]

I require to customize salesforce1 for my org with brand logo and colors. Please let me know how can I achieve this. Whether it is possible or not.

Answer (score 4):

1) Salesforce Menu--> Mobile Administration --> Salesforce1 --> Branding.

Here, You can find the options to edit the brandlogo.

[image: Salesforce1 Branding]

2) You can change the preferences/priority of the tabs/Custom Tabs displaying. If you don't need to use the "What I Follow" you can remove it.

Mobile Administration--> Mobile Navigation--> you can add/remove/move up/move down the tabs

3) Salesforce Menu--> Global Actions--> Publisher Layouts.

Here, you can align/add new/ remove the Quick action options.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Brand logo is coming on the first page as in I login, but I need it on the top blue bar as mentioned in the pic. I am unable to set it there

Comment: Hi SFDev, Logo will appear only in the first page after login but not as you request coz, while viewing in mobile it will be difficult I guess. Not Sure. Thanks.